# can snakemake choose a config file based on a parameter?

Tags: snakemake

I am building a snakemake workflow that will be used with different configurations.

Ideally I would be able to pass a parameter on commandline to determine which conf file to use.

I know how to pass a parameter e.g.

`--config parameter=value`

But as far as I can see this the gets added to the config dict.

So I can't define configfile using this parameter.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used `--configfile`. Provided you want to switch the choice of configfile at the command line, rather than within the snakemake run, this should be the argument you need.

Comment: That's indeed a solution, but I would like to implement it such that I do not have to bother about the paths when passing parameters. So if there is no alternative I'd go for it.

Comment: ahh.  I guess you could have a main Snakefile that calls a subworkflow and have the configfile for that subworkflow dynamically computed based on the contents of `config`. I don't have a solution for how to implement that at present though

Comment: @yahan I'm not sure to exactly understand what you want. Would a wrapper script around snakemake that sets the full path to the configfile and then calls snakemake do the trick ?

Comment: @bli, that would indeed be a solution also. Although I would prefer a solution that only uses snakemake. But thanks for the suggestion.